# Approximation of irrational numbers by rationals

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, approximation, real-numbers

Hardy and Wright in chapter on continued fractions prove the following theorem

> Let $x$ be an irrational number whose [simple continued fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleContinuedFraction.html) representation is given by $[a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n,\ldots] \big( \text{ie.} x=a_0 + \cfrac{1}{a_1 + \cfrac{1}{a_2 + \cfrac{1}{a_3 + {_\ddots}}}} \big)$. Then $ \bigl|x-\frac{p_n}{q_n} \bigl| < \frac{1}{q_n^2} $, where $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ convergent of $x$.

In the section on approximation of irrationals by rationals they say if we have an irrational say $x$ and an integer $q$  we want to know an upper bound for $\epsilon$ ( a positive number ) such that $\bigl|x-\frac{p}{q}\bigl| \le \epsilon $ ( $p$ is an integer ) ie. a relation of sorts mentioned in the above theorem.

My question is why study this sort of relationship between $q$ and $\epsilon$ at all ?  Is it not good enough if I approximate an irrational, say up to say $10$ decimal places ?

Comment: No, it is not good enough. Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, studying  these really "cheap"/"efficient" approximations is important when trying to solve some number theory problems, like Pell's equation.

Comment: I am self studying Hardy and Wright. I have not reached the chapter on Pell's equation yet. But thanks I will again look back once I reach chapter on Pell's Equations.